# Show that the drinking principle is not intuitionistic

Tags: logic, intuitionistic-logic

The drinking principle, namely 
$$ \exists x (p(x) \rightarrow \forall y p(y)) ,$$
aka the drinker paradox, can be infered using the rules of classical logic.

Is it possible to intuitionistically infer a formula which is not intuitionistically inferrable (such as $\lnot F \lor \lnot\lnot F$ or $\lnot F \lor F$ or $\lnot\lnot F \rightarrow F$ or $\lnot \exists x \lnot F \rightarrow \forall x F$ ...) from the drinking principle?

If  not, how do you prove it can't be inferred with the intuitionistic rules?

Comment: intuitionism is dead, for good reasons.

Comment: @Max: IntuitionISM may be dead as a movement that claims how mathematics in general should be done, but _intuitionistic logic_ is alive and kicking as an object of study in its own right.

Comment: no scienfific use since highly subjective; equally alive as number mysticism.

Comment: @Max: Unless you can produce the corpse of intuitionism, I wouldn't hurry to bury it in the past.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The drinker principle is not so strong that assuming it as an axiom will in itself yield classical logic.

One argument for this is that if $\varphi$ does not contain $x$ free, then $\varphi \to (\forall x)\varphi$ is intuitionistically valid. In particular, the drinker principle itself is intuitionistically valid in the special case where $p(x)$ does not mention $x$.

Thus, suppose that intuitionistic first-order logic plus Drinker proves $p\lor \neg p$ where $p$ is a *nullary predicate letter*. Take the supposed proof and replace every atomic formula other than $p$ by $\top$ everywhere in the proof. This replacement both preserves all inference rules, and all axioms are still provable after the replacement (equality axioms become things like $\top\to\top$ or $\top\to\top\to\top$, which need short proofs of themselves now).  Since there are no terms anywhere anymore, every instance of the Drinker axiom becomes $(\exists x)(\psi\to(\forall x)\psi)$ where $\psi$ does not contain $x$, which *is provable without the Drinker axiom*. Thus, we can construct a pure intuitionistic proof of $p\lor\neg p$ (which was not affected by the replacement) -- and this is known to be impossible.

---

To show that Drinker is not itself intuitionisticaly valid, we can show a [Kripke model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke_semantics#Semantics_of_intuitionistic_logic) where it is false.

The worlds are $w_0$, $w_1$, $w_2$ with $w_0<w_1$ and $w_0<w_2$, the domain is $\{1,2\}$ everywhere, and
$$ w_1\Vdash p(1) \qquad w_2\Vdash p(2) $$
Then $(\forall x)p(x)$ is *false* everywhere. So $p(1)\to(\forall x)p(x)$ is false in $w_1$ and $p(2)\to(\forall x)p(x)$ is false in $w_2$, and *both* of these are false in $w_0$. So there cannot be any witness of $p(x)\to(\forall x)p(x)$ in $w_0$, so the Drinker applied to $p$ is false in $w_0$.

Comment: Thank you. I think I'll have to study Kripke models, then ;)